# OAuth:How to sort string by lexicographical byte value ordering in java

Tags: java, oauth, 2-legged

hi i am trying to get request  token in from google apis.for getting request token i have to sort the parameter string by lexicographical byte value ordering in java code segment for the string

```
String datastring=URLEncoder.encode("oauth_version", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode("1.0", "UTF-8");


  datastring+="&"+URLEncoder.encode("oauth_nonce", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(System.currentTimeMillis()+"","UTF-8");

  datastring+="&"+URLEncoder.encode("oauth_timestamp", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000+"","UTF-8");

    datastring+="&"+URLEncoder.encode("oauth_consumer_key","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode("iriteshmehandiratta.appspot.com","UTF-8");

    datastring+="&"+URLEncoder.encode("oauth_signature_method","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode("RSA-SHA1", "UTF-8"); 

    datastring+="&"+URLEncoder.encode("oauth_signature", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(myrsakey, "UTF-8");

datastring+="&"+URLEncoder.encode("oauth_callback","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode("https://www.iriteshmehandiratta.appspot.com/authsub","UTF-8");

datastring+="&"+URLEncoder.encode("scope","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode("http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds","UTF-8");
```

i encoded parameters of query string now i have to lexicographically sort datastring  for sending a post request to URL https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken 
can any one please help how to sort this string lexicographically in java.

Comment: What do you mean sort a string? Do you have many strings and wan't to sort them in order?

Comment: no in this string there are many (key=value) pairs i have to sort these key value pairs in lexicographical order.so how to sort this string so that these key value pairs are in lexicographical order ??

Comment: That should have been part of your question. Why don't just order your  string concatenation following your desired order. All your keys are constant, so the order would be the same always.

Comment: To make myself clear, why don't you start with `oauth_callback`, then `oauth_consumer_key` and so on. That will guarantee lexicographical order without having to sort afterwards.

Comment: sorry actually i get confused with term lexicographical!!

Answer (score 0):

Use a Java [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html). This will allow you to use your OAuth parameters as key, then the value as the value you specified.

I suggest you add all your parameters **first** to the `TreeMap`, then iterate to get the `Set<Entry<String, String>>` to build your URL query string.

The Specification for `TreeMap` states:

> The map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by
>   a `Comparator` provided at map creation time, depending on which
>   constructor is used.